# How to select this <p> element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've posted my code below, what I'd like to do is select the 'p' element beneath the button that is clicked. I tried several selectors but I didn't succeed with any of them...

Here is my HTML:

```
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
var container = $("#container");
var allPanels = $(".panel");
var acc = $(".accordion");
var active = $(".active");


$(document).ready(function(){

$(".panel:first").show();
$(".accordion:first").toggleClass("active");

acc.click(function() {
    active.toggleClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    allPanels.hide();
    $(this).children('p').children('p').first().show();
    //The above selector is wrong.
  });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).next('div p').show();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, instead of `children` selector use `next` as it's not child element of `.accordion`, and as you are hiding `panel`,  `p` tag won't be visible, then use `$(this).next('.panel').show();`

```js
var container = $("#container");
var allPanels = $(".panel");
var acc = $(".accordion");
var active = $(".active");


$(document).ready(function(){

$(".panel:first").show();
$(".accordion:first").toggleClass("active");

acc.click(function() {
    active.toggleClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    allPanels.hide();
    $(this).next('.panel').show();
    //The above selector is wrong.
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum 1...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum 2...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum 3...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad! I could help.

Answer (score 5):

You're doing it wrong, now you're trying to select the `children` of `.accordion` which does not exist,  you can use **[next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)**.

```js
var container = $("#container");
var allPanels = $(".panel");
var acc = $(".accordion");
var active = $(".active");


$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".panel:first").show();
  $(".accordion:first").toggleClass("active");

  acc.click(function() {
    active.toggleClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    allPanels.hide();
    $(this).next('.panel').show();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[.next | Jquery API](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .next() method allows us to search through the immediately following
>   sibling of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery
>   object from the matching elements

So use the following to select immediate div

```
$(this).next('div')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make the buttons into radio buttons. You could then do the whole thing with CSS.

```
.accordion:checked + p {
    //your show css
}
```

Assuming, you only want to show one at a time. If not, use checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var container = $("#container");
var allPanels = $(".panel");
var acc = $(".accordion");
var active = $(".active");

allPanels.hide();
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".panel:first").show();
  $(".accordion:first").toggleClass("active");

  acc.click(function() {
    active.toggleClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    $('div.panel').not(this).hide();//hide other div
    $(this).next('div').show();//show div
    //The above selector is wrong.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Section 1</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Section 2</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Section 3</p>
</div>
```

1. Use this `.next()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.panel').hide();
  $('.panel:first').show();
  $('.accordion').click(function() {
  
  $(this).next().slideToggle().siblings('.panel').slideUp(500);
    
  });
});
```

```css
button{
  display:block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```